# How to know which class / module the super method is currently running?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to fix a bit of heavy metaprogramming bug in one of my gems.

TL;DR: I'll need to be able to know if the method is running inside a certain class / module

```rb
class ClassA
  def baz
    puts 'debug: inside ClassA'
    puts some_magic_method == ClassA
    super if defined? super
  end
end

module ModuleB
  def baz
    puts 'debug: inside ModuleB'
    puts some_magic_method == ModuleB
    super if defined? super
  end
end

class ClassC < ClassA
  include ModuleB

  def baz
    puts 'debug: inside ClassC'
    puts some_magic_method == ClassC
    super if defined? super
  end
end

class ClassD < ClassC
  def baz
    puts 'debug: inside ClassD'
    puts some_magic_method == ClassD
    super if defined? super
  end
end

class_d = ClassD.new
class_d.baz
# expected result:
# => debug: inside ClassD
# => true
# => debug: inside ClassC
# => true
# => debug: inside ModuleB
# => true
# => debug: inside ClassA
# => true
```

Some attempts I did was I tried to `puts self` inside each of the `baz` methods, but all of them I get an output of:

```rb
#<ClassD:0x007fe4ea824408>
#<ClassD:0x007fe4ea824408>
#<ClassD:0x007fe4ea824408>
#<ClassD:0x007fe4ea824408>
```

... which means `self` is always an instance of `ClassD` (which perfectly makes sense), however I couldn't find any other debugging way on how to get the "current" module / class. I was experimenting about whatever I could with the variables `_method_` and `binding`, but I could not find a way, unfortunately. Maybe I'm just missing something trivial here! Any help or guidance would be most appreciated! Thank you! :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I tried that just now, unfortunately they are all outputting `ClassD`

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution because I had to refactor the code, but I managed to solve my main problem by a workaround like below (if it helps anyone):

```rb
class ClassA
  defined_at = self

  define_method :baz do |*args|
    puts 'debug: inside ClassA'
    puts defined_at == ClassA
    super(*args) if defined? super
  end
end

module ModuleB
  defined_at = self

  define_method :baz do |*args|
    puts 'debug: inside ModuleB'
    puts defined_at == ModuleB
    super(*args) if defined? super
  end
end

class ClassC < ClassA
  include ModuleB

  defined_at = self

  define_method :baz do |*args|
    puts 'debug: inside ClassC'
    puts defined_at == ClassC
    super(*args) if defined? super
  end
end

class ClassD < ClassC
  defined_at = self

  define_method :baz do |*args|
    puts 'debug: inside ClassD'
    puts defined_at == ClassD
    super(*args) if defined? super
  end
end

class_d = ClassD.new
class_d.baz
# => debug: inside ClassD
# => true
# => debug: inside ClassC
# => true
# => debug: inside ModuleB
# => true
# => debug: inside ClassA
# => true
```

*P.S. needs `define_method` and not `def`, to be able to access the variables outside the `define_method` block, as using `def` threw me a `NameError undefined local variable or method 'defined_at'`*